# Java join doesn't wait for thread exit

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to synchronize this code: what I want is that the class Gioca waits until the class Gioco calls the method fine (fine should stop the thread) but as the Gioca class invokes the run method it prints on the console the string "Fine" even thow the class Gioco hasn't called the method fine() yet.

```
   public class Gioca implements Runnable
    {
        private int vite;
        private int recuperi;

        public Gioca() 
        {
            vite=3;
            recuperi=0;
        }  


        public void gioca()
        {   
            Thread t=new Thread(new Gioco(vite));

            try 
            {       
                t.start();
                t.join();
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) {}
            System.out.println("Fine");
        }

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            gioca();    
        }
    }





public class Gioco extends Canvas implements ActionListener, KeyListener, Runnable
{
    private int direzione;
    private Timer timer;
    private JFrame f;
    private int vite;
    private int velocità;
    private int spazio;
    private Personaggio p;
    private int pos;
    private LinkedList<Ostacolo> o;
    private Random r; 
    private int po;

    private Image imm1=new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("images/sfondo.jpg")).getImage();
    private Image imm2=new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("images/cuore.png")).getImage();

    public Gioco(int vite)
    {
        r=new Random();

        try
        {
            File file=new File("images/punteggio.txt"); 
            Scanner scanner=new Scanner(file);
            spazio=scanner.nextInt();              
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {}
        direzione=3;
        this.vite=vite;
        o=new LinkedList();
        for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
            o.add(new Ostacolo(Math.abs(400*i)+1000));
        p=new Personaggio();
        this.velocità=2;
        timer=new Timer(10, this);      
        f=new JFrame("Gioco");
        f.setSize(1000, 700);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setLocation(200,200);
        f.add(this);
        f.addKeyListener(this);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }  

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {
        if(direzione==2)
        {
            velocità-=2;
            if(velocità<2)
                velocità=2;
        }

        if(direzione==1)
            p.setY(5);

        if(direzione==0)
            p.setY(-5);

        spazio+=velocità;

        if(spazio%1000<10)
            velocità++;

        pos=(pos+velocità)%4500;
        po=-pos;

        for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
        {
            o.get(i).muovi(velocità);
            if(o.get(i).getX()<-100)
            {
                o.remove(i);
                o.add(new Ostacolo(i*400));
            }
        }

        verificaCollisioni();
        repaint();

    }

    public void verificaCollisioni()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
        {
            if(o.get(i).getX()>300 && o.get(i).getX()<350)
            {
                int r[]=o.get(i).getDimensioni();
                if(r[0]<p.getY() && r[1]>p.getY())
                {

                }
                else
                    fine();
            }
        }
    }

    private void fine()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

        timer.stop();

        try
        {            
            File file=new File("images/punteggio.txt");
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream f=new FileOutputStream(file);
            f.flush();
            String sPunteggio=String.valueOf(spazio);
            byte[] scrivi=sPunteggio.getBytes();
            f.write(scrivi);
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

        f.dispose();

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) 
    {
        int c=ke.getKeyCode();

        if(c == 40)
            direzione=1;
        if(c == 38)
            direzione=0;

        if(c==32)
            direzione=2;     
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        Image workspace=createImage(getWidth(),getHeight());
        Graphics2D buffer=(Graphics2D) workspace.getGraphics();

        buffer.drawImage(imm1, po, 0, this);             

        buffer.setColor(new Color(242, 54, 33));
        buffer.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 20));
        buffer.drawString(""+(spazio/100), 10, 20);   


        buffer.drawImage(imm2, 940, 4, this);
        buffer.setColor(new Color(13, 226, 13));
        buffer.drawString(""+vite, 920, 20);

        buffer.drawImage(p.getImage(), 300, p.getY(), this);

        for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
        {
            Ostacolo tmp=o.get(i);
            buffer.drawImage(tmp.getImage(), tmp.getX(),tmp.getY(), this);
        }

        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
        g2.drawImage(workspace, 0, 0, this);        
        buffer.dispose(); 
    } 

    public void update(Graphics g)
    {
        paint(g);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {direzione=3;}
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {}

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        f.setVisible(true);
        timer.start();

    }

}
```

This code, using the same instructions, works well

```
public class Campana implements Runnable{    
    private String suono;
    private int volte;
    public Campana(String suono,int volte) 
    {
      this.suono =suono;  
      this.volte=volte;  
    }
    public void run() 
    {
       for(int i=0;i<volte;i++) {
         System.out.println((i+1)+" "+suono);

       }
    }   
}

public class Suona {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Thread campana1=new Thread(new Campana("din", 5));                
        Thread campana2=new Thread(new Campana("don", 5));
        Thread campana3=new Thread(new Campana("dan", 5));
        try {
            campana1.start();
            campana1.join();
            campana2.start();
            campana2.join();
            campana3.start();
            campana3.join();




        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Suona.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe an `Exception` is caught and you're not handling it properly?

Comment: No, I've already tried to put a printStackTrace in every catch but no Exception are caught

Comment: Your code works fine. `public void run() 
    { f.setVisible(true);  timer.start();}` completes very quickly. I doesn't call the method `fine` at all; I don't understand why you think that the method `fine` should be called.

Comment: Because the timer.start should automatically call the actionPerformed() and in the actionPerformed there is a call to the fine method.

Comment: Anyway, maybe I understood, i should find a way to stop the run method until the function fine is called, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t.join();` in this case waits for `run` in `Gioco`to terminate. That method terminates after

```
f.setVisible(true);
timer.start();
```

have completed, which will be very fast since `Timer` will run `actionPerformed` a different thread from the one that `timer.start();` is called in. It does not wait until the timer has been stopped. You can fix this by introducing some form of synchronization in your `run` method. I would not recommend a while loop since that will waste resources on running the loop. Instead consider using a [`CountDownLatch` (javadoc link)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html):

Add this to `Gioco`:

```
private final CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

At the end of `fine()` call `doneSignal.countDown()`. And finally change your `run()` method in `Gioco` to something like this:

```
@Override
public void run() 
{
    f.setVisible(true);
    timer.start();
    try {
        doneSignal.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}//Logg this or something. Shouldn't really ever happen. 

}
```

Comment: I added a flag that becomes false when the function fine is called and a while(flag) into the run() and now it works. Thank you

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a way to wait for it to finish without using a while loop, which can be a bit inefficient.